# ANOVA for comparing same linear models

Tags: regression, anova, model-selection, model

I have trained two linear regressor models with the same response $Y$ and the same features $x_1$ and $x_2$, they are basically the same model, however only the training data differs: in model1 data was from country1 while the data from model2 was from country2

I run a F-Test Anova and I get a p-value of 0.07. I am not quite sure how to interpret this? isn't this a 7% significance level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't properly interpret an F-test on two models in the way that you did it. An F-test comparing two models requires them to be nested, in the sense that the predictors in one model form a subset of those in the other, and that the underlying data are the same. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17570/28500).

The best way to see if there is a difference between the 2 countries (which seems to be your interest) is to combine all the data, include an indicator variable for the `country`, and run your regression model with the `country` variable added to your set of predictors. The coefficient for the `country` variable then represents the systematic difference between the 2 countries, with the other predictors taken into account.

If you perform the analysis that way you can do a proper F-test, comparing models with versus without the `country` variable but both models built on all of the data for both countries. That will document the "significance" of the difference between the countries.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! If I do it the way you are suggesting, and get for example a p-value of 0.06, does the analysis stay the same? I mean, can I claim for example a 6% significance level?

Comment: @dm_reader yes; if the appropriate assumptions hold, the p-value is the fraction of experiments in which you would get at least that big a difference in the observed result even if there wasn't a true difference. But you shouldn't be focused on p-values in that way. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/134890/28500) for example. It's better to pre-specify a level of "significance" and stick with it. Or report the effect and confidence intervals for `country`.